# How to create an extjs grid structure from Json data

Tags: json, extjs

Just to be clear, I'm not asking about populating a grid's records using a json file. I want to create the grid's columns themselves using json. So as to recreate a grid. All the columns attributes, including width, locked, visible etc are to be saved in a json and that json has to be used to recreate the grid as it was.

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON is a string in var `myJSON` and is in format:

```
{
    myColumnDefinitions: [
        {
            text: "ColTitle1",
            dataIndex: "colfield1",
            width: 100
        },
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Your grid syntax should be as simple as

```
...
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
columns: Ext.JSON.decode(myJSON).myColumnDefinitions
...
```